# Delphi XE7 + TRegEx how correct?

Tags: regex, delphi, delphi-xe7

i have this text

```
  zero: false,
  contlen: 7640,
  ip_h: '52fe7c8fcffa04ffae',
  vc_h: '4cf12b21131231231cb802812bdf63b32',
  navPrefix: '/',
```

i want extract only this text - `52fe7c8fcffa04ffae`
i try use `ip_h: '(.*)'` but i get full line `ip_h: '52fe7c8fcffa04ffae',`

ill try many variants, with PHP this regular works fine... but in Delphi i cant do this..

RegexMagic show same
http://s21.postimg.org/ncbvkaag7/screenshot_913.png

in delphi with  `ip_h: '([^\n]*)'`
http://s21.postimg.org/ypyevhkyv/screenshot_914.png

Comment: Try `(?<=ip_h: ')[^']*(?=')`.

Comment: thx you, stribizhev!

Answer (score 3):

Formalizing the answer, the regex must be:

```
(?<=ip_h: ')[^']*(?=')
```

It uses the positive look-behind and look-ahead in order to get the match without single quotation marks.